# The use of control characters in postgres

Tags: postgresql, varchar

I am porting a legacy product over to Linux and its database over to postgres. Some of its data stored in varchars makes use a control character (ASCII 4)  in the data.

Are there any constraints or issues I need to be aware of when storing any control characters in postgres varchars?.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing you can not really put into varchar is 0x00, as this is a string terminator. 0x04 works just fine, just like other non-printable characters.